# Using an external OAuth provider for MVC4 authentication without membership or database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, asp.net-membership

I'm currently working on learning MVC4 and all the surrounding technologies.

The templates and wealth of functionality is quite overwhelming, but for my app I know:

1. A SQL database is not an option, they're too much and providers charge an arm and a leg
2. I'd like to be able to support Facebook authentication via OAuth and maybe Dropbox (to allow users to store documents and config etc if they opt to).

Out of the box there's a lot of existing templates and code for achieving this using `OAuthWebSecurity` in the `AuthConfig.cs` file, but this is by and large entirely entity framework focused (which is unsurprising given the prevalence and commercial interests SQL has within the Microsoft space).

I know you can do some poorman's authentication using web.config files and the such, but I was wondering if I could still make use of the built-in OAuth authentication tools, but minus all the entity-framework and database fuss? I'd still store some minimal data (access tokens and the such) in XML files etc.